# Double Linked List Implementation Alphabetically

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception, nodes

I'm attempting to build a linked list in java that is alphabetically organized but am having trouble with the logic of inserting and rearranging the list so far my implementation looks like, the data contains a name getter which is what it used to organize its position in the list:

```
    class Node
{

   private Data data;
   private Node nextNode;

   public Node (Data data, Node nextElement)
   {
      this.nextNode = nextElement;
      this.data = data;
   }

   public Node getNextNode ()
   {
      return nextNode;
   }

   public void setNextNode (Node nextNode)
   {
      this.nextNode = nextNode;
   }

   public Data getData ()
   {
      return data;
   }

   public void setData (Data data)
   {
      this.data = data;
   }
}
```

Then my linkedlist class is as follows:

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Node head = null;
    private int size = 0; 

    public void addData(Data c){
        this.size++;

        //empty case
        if(this.head == null){
            this.head = new Node(c, null);
            return;
        }



        Node current = this.head;
        Node previous = null;

        while(current.getNextNode()!=null&&previous.getData().getFirstName().compareTo(c.getFirstName())<=1){
            previous = current; // hold last element 
            current = current.getNextNode(); //move to next element
           }

        //insert into list
        if(current.getNextNode()==null){
            current.setNextNode(new Node(c,null)); //append end of List 
            previous = new Node(current.getData(), current);
        }else{
            Node insert = new Node(c, current); //prepend infront
            current.setNextNode(insert);
        }
```

Everything I try seems to give my nullpointer exceptions but maybe I am not getting the concepts right here. I start by checking if my list is empty and adding a node that points to null in front of it. When the new node is given, I loop through the current list till I find a spot and set the previous pointer to the current and the current becomes the new node pointing to the next item in the list (assuming we're not at the end of the list, where it just points to null).

I'm pretty lost at this point, where does my this.head go or do I have to do this through all edge cases? Any help in understanding would be appreciated

Comment: First of all the Node class implementation is not of a double Linked List. Each node of a double linked list contain reference to previous and next nodes.

Comment: Yeah I guess it is a single linked list but I have to keep track of both previous and next nodes for alphabetical implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is Double-LinkedList, it doesn't include a reference to the previous node.

Here how to insert in-order

```
        public void addData(Data c) {
            Node newNode = new Node(c, null);

            if (head == null) {
                head = newNode;
                size++;
                return;
            }

            Node current = head;
            Node prev = null;
            int comparison;

            while (current != null) {
                comparison = c.getFirstName().compareTo(current.getData().getFirstName());
                if (comparison == 0) {
                    return;
                } else if (comparison > 0) { /// greater than
                    if (current.nextNode == null) { // check if reach tail of the linked list add and break
                        current.nextNode = newNode;
                        break;
                    }
                } else { // less then
                    if (prev == null) { // check if it should be first then put and break
                        Node oldHead = head;
                        head = newNode;
                        head.nextNode = oldHead;
                        break;
                    }
                    prev.nextNode = newNode;
                    newNode.nextNode = current;
                    break;
                }
                prev = current;
                current = current.nextNode;
            }
            size++;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes much more sense. However for the comparison=0 case, data elements with the same "firstName" would not be added to the list. I think just keeping it as comparison >=0 would allow matching elements to just be appended in the position after

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addData(Data c) {
    this.size++;

    //empty case
    if (this.head == null) {
        this.head = new Node(c, null);
        return;
    }


    Node current = this.head;
    Node previous = null;

    //change in Code
    while (current.getNextNode() != null && current.getData().getFirstName().compareTo(c.getFirstName()) <= 1) {
        previous = current; // hold last element
        current = current.getNextNode(); //move to next element
    }

    //insert into list
    if (current.getNextNode() == null) {
        current.setNextNode(new Node(c, null)); //append end of List
        previous = new Node(current.getData(), current);
    } else {
        Node insert = new Node(c, current); //prepend infront
        current.setNextNode(insert);
    }

}
```